# How to install custom pre-requisites Visual Studio 2008 Setup Project

Tags: visual-studio-2008, setup-project, bootstrapper

I'm developing a VS2008 Setup project and I need to install (or not if already exists) some nested prerequisites.

I made two Manifest Package with Bootstrapper Manifest Generator for VS2008 and put them into Packages directory (C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages), so I can see and check them from prerequisites popup.
But when I run the setup.exe output file a strange thing happens: the setup of my project and the setup of the first prerequisite start simultaneously.

How I can set the opening sequencing?